# Using a static HTML page to access WordPress search

Tags: php, wordpress, search

So I have a `.html` page under my Wordpress website and I want to be able to use the search button on the static html page to search WordPress using the native search.php page, is that possible?

Is this correct? This is located inside my `test.html`:

```
<div class="search_bar-wrapper">
    <input type="text" class="search_bar search-input evt-search-input-wp" placeholder="Search"
    value="<?php echo get_search_query(true); ?>"/>
    <button class="btn-fh btn-secondary search-btn search-btn-overlay">
        <i class="custom-icon icon-icon_small_arrow_right"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="clearInput"><img src="/images/icon_close.svg" alt="" /></div>
</div>
```

Would I need to point a form="submit" and action=".." on the input instead? If so, what would the action need to point too?

Comment: On a standard WordPress install, non sub-domain, the search URL is `/` so that should be your `action` on the `form`. If you aren't in a standard install or are in a folder, you'll need to tweak that. Obviously, `<?php` won't work in that file since it is HTML, too. Your search input should have a name of just `s`.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes You Can did by add this code in your html page and Change Form Action Url With Your Wordpress Url**

```
<div class="search_bar-wrapper">
    <form action="https://wordpressdomainhere.com/" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="s" class="search_bar search-input evt-search-input-wp" placeholder="Search Here"/>
        <button class="btn-fh btn-secondary search-btn search-btn-overlay">
            <i class="custom-icon icon-icon_small_arrow_right"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="clearInput"><img src="/images/icon_close.svg" alt=""/></div>
    </form>
</div>
```